# Parallels mounter is unable to open the virtual hard disk

Tags: parallels

I installed parallel 9 with Windows 10 images installed on mac.

When I try to share mac folders to windows 10 manually I encounter following error
"Parallels mounter is unable to open the virtual hard disk". 
Following document : http://kb.parallels.com/en/112609 to do mannually installation.

Answer (score 0):

It fails because Parallel 9 does not support Windows 10. After upgrade to Parallel 12 and re-install Win 10. Everything goes fine.